# /.ssh/Authorized_keys is public php

Tags: php

When I open `http://mysite.com/.ssh/authorized_keys` a page opens and has the following information:

> ssh-rsa
>   AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAIEAvz7xl5Q7X+uobuGs9TMWh41A2icZNY2KLNgOHdsDl6E3kfxQhVxXCxBOl0QejWUeJatp0SU3y7//P5E35qDIMdEw8w7W2fpDdnKtmHhcvfs1BiKOP4BxwsE5JDhgt2zPt0RgxK/SR79q8g1oPi9V2xlDduCQ5mZq44vEwSLXVNU=

What is this? And is this Vulnerable? Can an attacker gain Admin privilege with it? If so, what will he do? How will he do an attack?

Version: PHP/5.3.18

Answer (score 2):

The `authorized_keys` file is used by ssh servers to store public keys for use in public/private key authentication.  On Linux, this file is usually in the `.ssh` directory in the user's home directory for whom the keys are for.  My guess is that the user you use has the web root as its home directory and when a public key was added for that user, this file was created.  It is possible that it is a sign of an intrusion, but it is more likely that it is normal since an attacker wouldn't need to add a public key, especially in .  Theoretically, there should be no harm in the file existing and be visible since the public key means nothing without someone with the private key, but there is also no need for people to be able to see it.  If you know you don't need the file you can delete it, or if you need it, you can put an `.htaccess` file in the directory to block web access.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your web root is set to your user home directory. This is definitely a security hole. Especially if you can access your private key file (id_rsa) which is also in the .ssh directory. You want to change your DocumentRoot setting in your vhost config.

Comment: The /ssh directory only has this file '/Authorized_keys'  nothing else